# image_transport/compressed_sub does not exist in android tutorial

Tags: android-core, ros-groovy, image-view, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Running a camera tutorial app](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_core#Running_a_tutorial_app) in [android_core](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_core), I get this error.

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/image _image_transport:=compressed
[ERROR] [1363589825.051878817]: Failed to load nodelet [/image_view_1363589824626933265] of type [image_view/image]: Unable to load plugin for transport 'compressed', error string:
According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/compressed_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/raw_sub image_transport/theora_sub
```

Running following command launchs a window without yielding error but nothing is shown on it.

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/image _image_transport:=raw
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/image _image_transport:=theora
```

Several question threads discuss similar error regarding [image_view](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view) but can't figure out how to work it around (I want to see an image that's taken by the camera on the `android` phone that's connected via USB. Camera app on android seems to be working fine). Thank you.

Ubuntu 12.10 Groovy, Android 4.0.4

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58405/image_transport/compressed_sub-does-not-exist-in-android-tutorial/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins installed?  Maybe try reinstalling it.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9